# How can labels be added to a HighlightGraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I would like to add the names of `vertL` to this `HighlightGraph`.  `edges.csv` is a two-column list of names, for example:
Bob   Susan
Susan  Jane
Jane  Susan
Susan  Bob

```
edges = Import["edges.csv"];
edgeList = Table[
  edgelist[[row, 1]] -> edges[[row, 2]],
  {row, 1, Length[edges]}]
vertL = VertexList[edgeList]
dc = DegreeCentrality[edgelist]
dc = N[Rescale[dc]]
assign = Thread[vertList -> dc]
HighlightGraph[edgeList, vertL, VertexSize -> assign]
```

Answer (score 1):

[HighlightGraph >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HighlightGraph.html):

> `HighlightGraph` *takes the same options* as `Graph`.

So you can use the option `VertexLabels`.

```
SeedRandom[123]
edges = DeleteDuplicates@RandomChoice[Subsets[CharacterRange["A", "F"], {2}], 10];
edgeList = Rule @@@ edges;
vertL = VertexList[edgeList];
dc = N@Rescale@DegreeCentrality[edgeList];
assign = Thread[vertL -> dc];

HighlightGraph[edgeList, vertL, VertexSize -> assign, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexLabelStyle -> 20]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `SetProperty` to add options to the graph object produced by `HighlightGraph`

```
g2 = HighlightGraph[edgeList, vertL, VertexSize -> assign];
SetProperty[g2, {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexLabelStyle -> 20}]
```

> same picture